# how to export extensions of Google Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser-addons, migration, export

I am finally migrating to Ubuntu and would like to know if it is possible to export my favorite Chrome extensions so that I could import them in my new Chrome in Ubuntu?

Anybody knows please share with us this information.

Thanks

Comment: Just save the Application Data folder and copy it back when you've deleted Ubuntu and installed Win back. (Put the fun aside, if you save your application data ,(folders related to chrome), that should be enough if you copy them to your linux .chrome/whatever folder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or you can use the following command to export

```
- chrome://extensions/
- shift+ctrl+j
- paste this :
returnExtensionsData=function(a){var o=[];for(var i=0,e=a.extensions,len=a.extensions.length;i<len;i++){o.push({id:e[i].id,name:e[i].name});}console.log('var extdata='+JSON.stringify(o)+';');};requestExtensionsData();
```

If you want to import , paste the output in the destination browser and run

```
 returnExtensionsData=function(a){var o={};for(var i=0,e=a.extensions,len=e.length;i<len;i++){o[e[i].id]={name:e[i].name};}importExtensionsData(o);};
 function importExtensionsData(exts){var version=/Chrome\/([\.\d]+)/.exec(navigator.appVersion)[1];var lang=navigator.language;for(var i=0,len=extdata.length;i<len;i++){if(!exts[extdata[i].id]){var url='https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D'+extdata[i].id+'%26uc%26lang%3D'+lang+'&prod=chrome&prodversion='+version;con
```

More details [here](http://docs.google.com/View?id=dgwkttgj_25f9fp2v6f).

Comment: This looks amazing, MNH! Would you happen to know of an extension to handle all that properly with no (or minor) issues?

Comment: this doesn't work anymore. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'extensions' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Dev version of Chrome, it [supports ExtensionSync](http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/google-chrome-dev-chanel-gets-extension-sync.html)

Else refer to Shiki's comment.

> Just save the Application Data folder
>   and copy it back when you've deleted
>   Ubuntu and installed Win back. (Put
>   the fun aside, if you save your
>   application data ,(folders related to
>   chrome), that should be enough if you
>   copy them to your linux

Comment: extension **data** syncing, that's what it is. it won't work unless you have same extensions installed in each end.