# How can I export my extensions in Chrome 15?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Google Chrome 15, how can I export my extensions to another computer?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/154770/how-to-export-extensions-of-google-chrome) question doesn't apply to Chrome version 15.

I'm trying to copy an extension that no longer exists in the [webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home).

Comment: exactly which extensions are you using? there might be better alternatives in web store or the developer might have renamed the extension...

Answer (score 2):

You can find All extension  here (what you have installed on Google Chrome):

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

if you have created a profile in Chrome then it will be present in `Profile Name` instead of `Default` in above address. Just Copy extension file and paste in newer Chrome. You must be careful extension may be incompatible.

Comment: using the "Load unpacked extension" in Chrome://extensions

Comment: Please elaborate how to pull it using Load Unpacked Extension?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Synch function? *Wrench->Options->Personal Stuff->Sync->Set up synch*. Then you can select to include your extensions.

Comment: Syncing doesn't transfer extension options. You have to migrate the whole profile.

Comment: @dnbtv, I do not understand what you mean. There is an extension option in the *Configure synch* pagelet. What then is that for?

Comment: That syncs only extensions. You have to re-configure their preferences on the new machine.

Comment: I think it wont work....not for extensions that are no longer in web store...

Answer (score -1):

This guide explains how you can migrate your profile from computer to the next, allowing you to bring your extensions with you:

http://www.todayisearched.com/2010/05/export-chrome-extensions.html

Comment: I don't think this relates to Chrome V. 15

Comment: Could you perhaps explain this instead? We prefer that you explain how to do things, as opposed to simply posting links

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Share Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-extensions/chdafcbnfkfenoeejpaeenpdamhmalhe/related) extension which allows you to export as BBCode, HTML, Wiki or text list as well as share via Twitter.

Comment: That extension doesn't not do what the OP requested.